# Get Date in a particular format in python

Tags: python, date

I have to get the date of the day approximately one month before from today in python.
The resulting string should be of the format `yyyy/mm/dd`

The date has to be approximate, so things like considering the leap year and all can be avoided (or if easy can be incorporated as well)

I have written the following code for the above problem

```
from datetime import date
tup=list(date.today().timetuple()[0:3])
if (tup[1]==1):
    tup[1]=12
    tup[0]-=1
else:
   tup[1]-=1
   if tup[1]==2:
      tup[2]=min(28,tup[2])
   else if tup[1] in [4,6,9,11]:
      tup[2]=min(30,tup[2])
print '/'.join([str(x) for x in tup])
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve the above problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` class in conjunction with the `timedelta` function.

i.e.

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> days=30
>>> d = date.today() - timedelta(days=days)
>>> print d
2014-06-29
```

Then, to format:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strftime(d, "%Y/%m/%d")
>>> print dt
2014/06/29
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative solution using a third-party package called [`Delorean`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Delorean):

```
>>> from delorean import Delorean
>>> d = Delorean()
>>> d.last_month().date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
'2014/06/29'
```

Comment: Will using a third-party package on a server be an additional overhead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateUtil's [`relativedelta`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) function for this functionality as well. It handles days in a month and leap years appropriately, like alecxe's library does.

If you don't have the DateUtil library, first install that

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Then you can utilize it like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> now = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> now + relativedelta(months=1)
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 29, 0, 32, 51, 843000)
>>> now + relativedelta(months=-1)
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 29, 0, 32, 51, 843000)
```

Finally, to format it, you need to use the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) function.

```
>>> (now + relativedelta(months=-1)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
'2014/06/29'
```

Answer (score 0):

datetime is the correct module here..

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Hope this helps.